# IE doesn't populate the areas in image map

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I wonder where is the problem in this code and those areas 
why it's work in the google chrome 
but when i try it on IE and Edge it's just  work in the right image 
you can test the code in any html online editor

[try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/7pp6n7rg/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg/488px-Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg.png"         width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<img src="http://www.hdiphonewallpapers.us/phone-wallpapers/mobilewallpaper/1293W01Z93120-34333.jpg" usemap="myMap"> 


<map name="planetmap">
 <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="javascript:alert('suuun');">
 <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3"  href="javascript:alert('suuun');">
 <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8"  href="javascript:alert('suuun');">>
</map>
<map name="myMap" >  
 <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,126" href="javascript:alert('suuun');">
  <area shape="rect"  id="lblTotalQtyVal" href="javascript:alert('suuun');">
  <area shape="rect" coords="3,206,152,223" id="lblTotalQty" href="javascript:alert('Hello');">
  <area id="cboWarehouse" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect"       coords="71,21,218,39">
 <area id="lblWarehouse" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="5,21,65,40">
  <area id="lblCurrentQtyVal" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="3,259,79,277">
  <area id="lblCurrentQty" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="3,246,79,259">
  <area id="lblNetQtyVal" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="80,259,156,277">
  <area id="lblNetQty" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="80,246,156,259">
  <area id="btnQuickUnload" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="166,246,236,280">
  <area id="btnUnloadVan"  href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="85,283,155,317">
  <area id="btnNextScreen" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="219,21,237,39">
  <area id="cboStatus" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="71,40,237,58">
  <area id="lblStatus" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="5,40,55,59">
 <area id="btnNext" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="166,283,236,317">
 <area id="btnClear" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="199,79,237,97">
 <area id="btnFind" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="159,79,197,97">
  <area id="txtFind" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="3,79,158,97">
  <area id="lblCat" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="3,60,178,78">
  <area id="btnViewAll" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="219,60,237,78">
  <area id="btnFavr" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" shape="rect" coords="199,60,217,78">
   <area shape="rect" coords="179,60,197,78" id="btnMore" href="javascript:alert('Hello');" >
  <area shape="rect" id="lblSelectedItem" href="javascript:alert('Hello');">
  <area  shape="rect" coords="3,283,73,317"  id="btnBack" href="javascript:alert('Hello');">
   <area shape="rect" coords="3,98,237,206" id="grdItem" href="javascript:alert('Hello');">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set it up for us in an online editor like http://jsfiddle.net. What exactly doesn't work, though? Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: what doesn't work was populating the areas on image in IE 
but i fixed it 
see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys I figured out the problem 
it's IE needs hash sign before map name `usemap="myMap"` 
while in chrome it's not a problem to put the name with hash sign 
or without it

`<img src="http://www.hdiphonewallpapers.us/phone-wallpapers/mobilewallpaper/1293W01Z93120-34333.jpg" usemap="myMap">`